# How do i make one button play a list of sounds randomly each time its being pressed?

Tags: java, android

I know how to make 1 button play 1 audio file but how do u make 1 button play multiple Sound files randomly?

Answer (score 0):

Add all the audio's uri in a ArrayList and select random uri from it as -

```
ArrayList<Uri> list = new ArrayList();
list.add(audio1Uri1);
list.add(audio1Uri2);
list.add(audio1Uri3);

Collections.shuffle(list);

System.out.println("" + list);
//This will give you random songs everytime. Pass the element one by one to media player. And play the next song by checking if the previous one has finished
```

Comment: If this helped u, check the tick mark on left side of my answer to accept it, which can be helpful for others too.

Comment: I cant seem to get the same code as you when i type it in, it doesnt find ran.next, and could you show me a video or article to further explain what all of the code does?. Thanks for helping.